# attrs.$observe on children in angular directive?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, directive, children

Is it possible to watch the attrs of children in a directive using $observe?

I have this HTML that gets rendered with my "monitor" directive.

```
<monitor>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Monitor <expand class="pull-right"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="expand()"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></button></expand>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body monitor-blink">
            <h4 class="alert-title no-margin">No monitoring </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</monitor>
```

The `<div class="panel panel-default">` will become `<div class="panel panel-default expand">` and I'm trying to make changes inside my dom when that class gets added.

I thought about forcing a $apply but been trying to get this to work with $observe. How do I attrs.$observer on a child attribute?

Like this?

```
attr.$observe(attrs, function(key, val) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

What goes into the first argument of the `$observer`? That's where I'm stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `$oberve` is to watch for interpolated bindings on your directive (such as `some-dynamic-attribute="{{someValue}}"`).

I don't know how this child class is set, but you have two scenarios: either it is set by Angular, in which case you should search for what causes angular to set this class and then watch for the same event.

Or if it is set by a third party library, you might do something like this:

```
var theChildElement = ...;
scope.$watch(function() { return theChildElement.className; }, function(className) {
  // className is the list of classes of that child element, called every time this list changes
});
```

This will work, however that watcher could be a bit expensive if you have an heavy angular application. In a small one it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you. The scope.$watch worked perfectly for the element I needed to watch ... I knew there was a jquery method I wasn't thinking of (className or attr('class'). Anyways, thanks again.